# images in a CSS modal box

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog

I have a modal box (CSS) and For some reason I cannot get images in the box to display horizontally, with out messing up the box? when I float the images in the gallery id  they leave the modal box?
html

```
<head>
    <title>Design and Development</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|Ubuntu+Condensed|Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
         <h1>PERSON</h1>

         <h2>Front-End Design + Development</h2>

    </header>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#aboutModal">ABOUT</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#workModal">WORK</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#contactModal">CONTACT</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="aboutModal" class="modalDialog">
        <div>   <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>

                <h1>ABOUT</h1>

            <img src="images/me.jpg">
            <p><strong>Hello!</strong>
                <br></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="workModal" class="modalDialog">
        <div>   <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>

                <h1>WORK</h1>

            <ul id="gallery">
                <li> <a href="images/yogasite.png">
          <img src="https://lh3.ggpht.com/rIVPZ4wNQ1uWIWoFcnZ-KjjUHfTFskcgwzEoAEqDAb8LjPdtXWM5NLqCLx9BRpEF1Dc=w300">

         </a>

                </li>
                <li> <a href="images/yogasite.png">
          <img src="https://lh3.ggpht.com/rIVPZ4wNQ1uWIWoFcnZ-KjjUHfTFskcgwzEoAEqDAb8LjPdtXWM5NLqCLx9BRpEF1Dc=w300" alt="">

         </a>

                </li>
                <li> <a href="images/yogasite.png">
          <img src="images/yogasite.pnghttps://lh3.ggpht.com/rIVPZ4wNQ1uWIWoFcnZ-KjjUHfTFskcgwzEoAEqDAb8LjPdtXWM5NLqCLx9BRpEF1Dc=w300" alt="">

         </a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="contactModal" class="modalDialog">
        <div>   <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>

                <h1>CONTACT</h1>


                <br>
                <br>I am currently looking for work.</p>
            <img src="images/06-magnify-icon-32.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

heres the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cpxd63a1/1/

Comment: Please create an isolated code example of the issue you having. You’ve literally pasted your entire site into the jsfiddle.

Comment: @zaqx... you serious?

Comment: If you need help check out Stack Overflow’s tips on creating minimal code examples: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve or feel free to ask here.